# ASP.net core 2.0 external login error (Exception: OAuth token endpoint failure: Status: ProxyAuthenticationRequired;Headers: Cache-Control: no-cache)

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-2.0

I have followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-s/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x).
When i launch my localhost, and when i click on google to login, it redirects me to google sign-in page (credentials are entered) and when i click signin it throws me below error.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   Exception: OAuth token endpoint failure: Status:
>   ProxyAuthenticationRequired;Headers: Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Connection: close Pragma: no-cache Proxy-Authenticate: NEGOTIATE,
>   NTLM, BASIC realm="IWA_Direct" Proxy-Connection: close ;Body: ;

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
    Configuration = configuration;
}
public IConfiguration Configuration {
    get;
}
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddDbContext < ApplicationDbContext > (options = >
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddIdentity < ApplicationUser, IdentityRole > ()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores < ApplicationDbContext > ()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient < IEmailSender, EmailSender > ();
    services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions = > {
        googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["GoogleID"];
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["GoogleSecret"];
    });
    services.Configure < MvcOptions > (options = > {
        options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
    });
    services.AddMvc();
}
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseBrowserLink();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    } else {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps(301, 5001);
    app.UseRewriter(options);
    app.UseMvc(routes = > {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

I am using asp.net core 2.0. Need help in resolving this issue.

Comment: I was facing similar issue in company and it was due to PROXY which was blocking the request. Either add header in the proxy or by pass the proxy and it will work.